# 404 route not found exception handling in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, twig

I want to create a template for page not found. whenever 404 no route found exception is throwing need to redirect to page. As that is not in proper UI way. I tried steps from this URL

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

I am new to symfony . followed steps until service.yml and created customExceptionController.php and I dont know what to do next step and I am getting error like

[image]

How to fix this issue.Please anyone help me to get out of this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show what you have in the _your_ `CustomExceptionController` file.

Comment: public function showAction()
{
    return $this->render('templates:bundles:twigBundle:Exception:error.html.twig');
}

Comment: But no response still ., 404 not found exception is throwing

Comment: Add the _full_ content of the file to your question. The error message clearly states that the file is in the first place, but you've probably either mis-spelled the class name, or put in the wrong namespace.

Comment: Now I changed it., its running now and no changes for error exception still as like same.. "code":404,"message":"Not Found","exception":[{"message":"No route found for \"GET

Comment: you do not need to override the controller nor the yaml file. If you used the right path (app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig) Symfony will show the view you've created

Comment: I have created html twig in this path. and I didnt gave any changes in yaml. still I get same exception instead of twig

Answer (score 0):

In the `dev` environment, you will always see the default exception page which is meant to ease debugging issues. If you want to see how a certain error page looks like in the `prod` environment (because you maybe created a custom template for it), you need to access a special URL that is only available for this purpose in the `dev` enviromnent (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development). In your case, this URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/_error/404